# How to read csv's into Pandas that use a quote separator but also non-escaped left and right double quotes that need to be ignored

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have CSV files that need to be read in that have some lines that read fine but others that look like this:

```
2022-10-04, "", some data in col3, moredata, "data in quotes, like the size for this thing is 23'' x \28" with this description, moredata

2022-10-05, "", some data in col3, moredata, "data in quotes, like the size for this thing is 23“ x \28" with this description, moredata
```

so the problem I can't solve is: this is a CSV - so commas are the delimiter, and it uses double quote separators for values that have multiple commas in them that are not supposed to be read as delimiters, ok I figured out how to account for that in pandas read_csv options,

BUT,
inside some of the quote separated fields, when there are numbers in inches, they use all 4 of:

escaped double quotes: `\"`

double single quotes: `''`

AND left or right double quotes, like: `“`  that are not escaped, that I think might be getting misread as quote separator characters, and I am not sure how to ignore them.

I can't figure out how to get the CSV to read right in Pandas, or any other method. There are a lot of rows of data that use these left and right double quotes without escaping them, so if a row looks anything like:

```
something, "one value with 23'', 25\", 20“, ...", val 3, val_4
```

It has 4 values,

and the value `"one value with 23'', 25\", 20“, end value"` should be read in as 1 value: `value with 23'', 25\", 20“, end value`

But all the options I Have tried either end up skipping these rows or getting them read into the wrong columns, or just give errors and reading the data into a dataframe fails

Edit: per request from BeRT2me, here is a better example of a row from one of the CSV with 'actual' data. (I cannot provide any of the 'actual' values so put in fake data in the same format)

headers:
`start_date,end_date,product_code,available,category_rank,brand,name,category,price`

row of data in the csv:

`2022-10-05,2022-10-10,3716372837,1.0,"",brand1,"Puzzle map of the world, 300 pieces, 23” x 15\", great for all ages",Games,39.99`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide an example using *actual* values? It's hard to interpret what's going on with random phrase like "some data in col 3", "moredata", "something", "val 3" everywhere. Aka, provide something that code can be run on for expected input/output.

Comment: open your data with a text editor and paste it in your question. paste 5-6 rows.

Comment: Do you mean `start_date, end_date, product_code...`?

Comment: You may want to look in to: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `test.txt`:

```
start_date, end_date, product_code, available, category_rank, brand,name,category,price
2022-10-05,2022-10-10,3716372837,1.0,"",brand1,"Puzzle, 300'' p, 23” x 15\", great",Games,39.99
```

Doing:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', escapechar='\\')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   start_date    end_date   product_code   available   category_rank   brand                               name category  price
0  2022-10-05  2022-10-10     3716372837         1.0             NaN  brand1  Puzzle, 300'' p, 23” x 15", great    Games  39.99
```